# Unintended uicollectionview cell shuffling

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a slight UI bug I am having trouble solving.

`Scenario:` I have 3 horizontal video thumbnails. The one in the middle has a lock icon signalling "only watchable when subscribed". The other thumbnails have no lock icons because they are free to watch. Upon logging in or out, I notice the 3 thumbnails shuffle for a split second. They then shuffle back to their intended positions but now the 3rd video has a lock icon. And if I repeat, the first has a lock icon.

A `Notification Center` post alerts when the user has signed in or out and we reload our data:

```
func reloadCollection() {
    // reload data
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let section = self.sections[indexPath.section]

    let data = section.items[self.isInfinityScrolling ? (indexPath.row % self.sections[indexPath.section].items.count) : indexPath.row]

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCell
    cell.configWithItem(data)
    return cell

}

func configWithItem(_ item: CollectionLabeledItem) {
    // get images, titles, etc

    if item.lockStyle != nil {
        self.lockStyle = item.lockStyle!
    }
    // nil = empty || no lock icon
    // lockStyle = locked or unlocked
}
```

When I breakpoint my reloadCollection(), the method it calls inside works properly:

```
if video.subscriptionRequired {
     if isLoggedIn() {
         self.lockStyle = .unlocked
     }
     else {
         self.lockStyle = .locked
     }
 }
```

I also am using prepareForReuse:

```
var prepareForReuseCallback: (() -> Void)!

func prepareForReuse(){
    if self.prepareForReuseCallback != nil {
        self.prepareForReuseCallback()
    }
}
```

I have a suspicion the shuffling of the cells cause some misaligned logic during the reload, but I am unable to find any solutions thus far. Thank you in advance, looking forward to hear from the wonderful community!